# Rscript and UNC paths

Tags: r, cmd, unc

I have an R script that I would like to run from the command line using `Rscript.exe` in Windows. The script runs fine if I open it in RStudio but when I run it through Rscript in the command line it fails because I have UNC paths in my script. For example,

```
read.csv("//server/directory/file.csv/")
```

Rscript fails and says the directory does not exist. Is there anyway to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does `read.csv("//server/directory/file.csv")` work? If not can you give your code so that we can reproduce it? (I am not sure whether you need `normalizePath` at all)

Comment: @Christoph  ```read.csv("//server/directory/file.csv")``` works. I have tried my script with only that line and get the same error. To be clearer, if I run the script from RStudio it works; however if I try to run it from the command line using ```Rscript myscript.R``` then I get an error.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example `myscript.R`?

Comment: I am not able to add a reproducible example because the path is not public but on further inspection the problem is with permission to the directories and not with Rscript. As a note for future readers of this post; I can confirm that I can use Rscript with UNC paths.