# Is coefplot2 still supported for current version of R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes"

Tags: r, coefplot

I use coefplot2 to plot regression estimates for ecological data. I have a new computer so just setting up. All other packages and code working for new set-up. But dearly love to keep using coefplot2 but need assistance.

I have tried to install coefplot2 using R forge and bolker source sites as recommended in several posts here and on other sites as follows, with no luck.

```
install.packages("coefplot2", repos="http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R", type="source")

install.packages("coefplot2",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")

> install.packages("coefplot2", repos="http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R", type="source")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘\\staff.ad.griffith.edu.au/ud/fr/s2903680/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R/src/contrib/coefplot2_0.1.3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1357869 bytes (1.3 MB)
downloaded 1.3 MB

'\\staff.ad.griffith.edu.au\ud\fr\s2903680\Desktop\Research\data_analysis_pumice\havre'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'coefplot2' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'coefplot2'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'coefplot2'
* removing '\\staff.ad.griffith.edu.au/ud/fr/s2903680/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/coefplot2'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘coefplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Have installed previous dependencies eg installation asked for 'reshape' to be installed. I wonder do I need to install 'rtools'. Seems silly as I am not a developer - but if it works I'll do it.

Comment: Hi, what R version are you running? Seems like it has not been updated in a very long time. My best guess would be just to look into the github and tweak the contents of the package: https://github.com/palday/coefplot2

Comment: Installing from github appears to work for me (I'm on ubuntu): `remotes::install_github("palday/coefplot2", subdir = "pkg")`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for replies. I definitely have the latest version of R as only just installed it. Are you able to provide more detailed instructions for 'github' for the uninitiated? I have not used it before. I had a look - but quite unsure at this stage how to 'tweak' the package or install from here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

(Not really an answer but too long for a comment)

For me, both install-with-source-from-repo:

```
install.packages("coefplot2",
    repos="http://www.math.mcmaster.ca/bolker/R",
    type="source")
```

and install-from-github:

```
 remotes::install_github("palday/coefplot2",
           subdir = "pkg")
```

work (the latter is just a copy/mirror of an R-forge repo) - the latter is a little more up to date.

My guess is that the problem is with the network drive/UNC path: there are other SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702472/rsript-and-unc-paths?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41285716/unc-paths-for-read-csv-in-r) that suggest this could be a problem.

Can you try `install.packages()` with `lib='some_local_directory'` (and then `library("coefplot2",lib.loc='some_local_directory')` ?

The last part of this comment is that I've transitioned from `coefplot2` to `broom` (for coefficient tables) + `ggplot2`/`dotwhisker` - it's a more modular system that's more flexible and handles a broader range of model types. (Assuming you're OK with `ggplot2` solutions.)

Comment: Hi Ben, Much appreciated. I had suspected that lib location might be a problem. But as all other libraries working thought I was incorrect. Your solution completely worked. So will use coefplot2 for now and then teach myself broom/ggplot2 methods. Any useful resources on these? Many thanks, Eleanor

Answer (score 0):

Try install.packages("coefplot2", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")